# python - string vs list types and NoneType

Tags: python

Why does this evaluate to type string:

```
>>> strng = 'spam'
>>> type(strng.replace('a', 'A')) 
>>> <type 'str'>
```

but this evaluates to type NoneType?

```
>>> list_a = ['spam']
>>> type(list_a.append('eggs')) 
>>> <type 'NoneType'>
```

Answer (score 6):

Because the `append` method on the list returns a None (or, said another way... doesn't return anything), as it mutates the list.

Most, if not all, mutating methods in python's standard library act this way.

`replace` on the string, does not mutate, as python strings are immutable.  A new string is returned with the replacements made.

Answer (score 4):

If you look at your commands a bit more, you will see this:

```
>>> strng.replace('a', 'A')
'spAm'
>>>
```

Notice how this method returns something. When you call `type()`, you are basically calling this:

```
>>> type('spAm')
<type 'str'>
>>>
```

---

Now your next line of code:

```
>>> list_a.append('eggs')
>>>
```

Notice that *nothing was returned*. When you call `type()` on this, you are basically calling `type()` with a `None` parameter:

```
>>> type(None)
<type 'NoneType'>
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

Strings are immutable, so the only reasonable thing for `replace` to do would be to return the changed value. Lists are mutable, though, so `append` doesn't have to return anything, and if there is no explicit `return`, it returns `None`. You could say that `append` *should* return something, but that may lead people to believe that `append` does *not* mutate the list.

Answer (score 2):

Because [str.replace()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) returns a new string with the modified value, while [list.append()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) modifies the list in place, not returning a value.